# Michelson: two potential bugs in type checker / spec

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, type-checker

**TL;DR** looks like 1 bug in spec and one more in type checker for alphanet.

Someone please review and comment on this behavior :)

```
parameter unit;
storage string;
code { DROP;
       PUSH int 3;
       PUSH (option int) None;
       IF_NONE { DROP;
                 PUSH @x (string :tagX) "bt1";
                 PUSH @y string"bt2";
                 PUSH @z (string :tagZ) "bt3";
               }
               { DROP;
                 DROP;
                 PUSH string "bf1";
                 PUSH (string :tagY) "bf2";
                 PUSH string "bf3";
               };
       PUSH @after_if (string :newTag) "after_if";
       CONCAT;
       DROP; DROP; DROP;
       PUSH string "Hello Tezos!";
       NIL operation;
       PAIR;
      };
```

On alphanet this script type checks well.

There are two problems with it:

### Problem one (potential bug in spec)

```
   iff   bt :: [ 'S -> 'b : 'S]
         bf :: [ 'a : 'S -> 'b : 'S]
```

according to spec, but code in the sample behaves differently: `IF_NONE :: option 'a : [ int : (pair unit string) ]    ->   'b : [ string : string : string : (pair unit string) ]`

So perhaps there's a bug in spec and `IF_NONE :: option 'a : 'X   ->   'b : 'Y` (which is OK)

### Problem two (potential bug in type checker)

If you follow type annotations, it will be evident that different branches of if pushed `string :tagX : string : string :tagZ` while other pushed `string  : string :tagY : string` .

But surprisingly in the output of type checker we see `/* [ @after_if string :newTag : string : string : string ] */` which is well .. strange.
Looks like a bug in type checker that it accidentally erases type annotations when they differ for various branches of if (or maybe just for branches of if disregard to one other).

---

Dump of type checker for the sample:

```
Well typed
Gas remaining: 399177 units remaining
{ parameter unit ;
  storage string ;
  code { /* [ pair (unit @parameter) (string @storage) ] */
         DROP
         /* [] */ ;
         PUSH int 3
         /* [ int ] */ ;
         PUSH (option int) None
         /* [ option int : int ] */ ;
         IF_NONE
           { /* [ int ] */
             DROP
             /* [] */ ;
             PUSH @x (string :tagX) "bt1"
             /* [ @x string :tagX ] */ ;
             PUSH @y string "bt2"
             /* [ @y string : @x string :tagX ] */ ;
             PUSH @z (string :tagZ) "bt3"
             /* [ @z string :tagZ : @y string : @x string :tagX ] */ }
           { /* [ int : int ] */
             DROP
             /* [ int ] */ ;
             DROP
             /* [] */ ;
             PUSH string "bf1"
             /* [ string ] */ ;
             PUSH (string :tagY) "bf2"
             /* [ string :tagY : string ] */ ;
             PUSH string "bf3"
             /* [ string : string :tagY : string ] */ } ;
         PUSH @after_if
           (string :newTag)
           "after_if"
         /* [ @after_if string :newTag : string : string : string ] */ ;
         CONCAT
         /* [ string : string : string ] */ ;
         DROP
         /* [ string : string ] */ ;
         DROP
         /* [ string ] */ ;
         DROP
         /* [] */ ;
         PUSH string "Hello Tezos!"
         /* [ string ] */ ;
         NIL operation
         /* [ list operation : string ] */ ;
         PAIR
         /* [ pair (list operation) string ] */ } }
```

Comment: Bug reports are better filed using the ticket system on Gitlab. StackExchange is for questions

Answer (score 2):

Created: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/471

This ticket will be closed.